# Out of memory when reading a gif file in wpf (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

I wrote a control read gif file using c# as follows:

```
public class AnimatedGIFControl : System.Windows.Controls.Image
    {

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsPlayProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsPlay", typeof(bool), typeof(AnimatedGIFControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsPlayChanged)));

    public bool IsPlay
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)this.GetValue(IsPlayProperty); 
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(IsPlayProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private static void OnIsPlayChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            (d as AnimatedGIFControl).StartAnimate();
        }
        else
        {
            (d as AnimatedGIFControl).StopAnimate();
        }            
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty GifSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("GifSource", typeof(string), typeof(AnimatedGIFControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnGifSourceChanged)));

    public string GifSource
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)this.GetValue(GifSourceProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(GifSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private static void OnGifSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (d as AnimatedGIFControl).AnimatedGIFControl_Loaded();
    }

    private Bitmap _bitmap; // Local bitmap member to cache image resource
    public delegate void FrameUpdatedEventHandler();


    /// <summary>
    /// Delete local bitmap resource
    /// Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183539(VS.85).aspx
    /// </summary>
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

    /// <summary>
    /// Override the OnInitialized method
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInitialized(e);
        this.Unloaded += new RoutedEventHandler(AnimatedGIFControl_Unloaded);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load the embedded image for the Image.Source
    /// </summary>       
    public void AnimatedGIFControl_Loaded()
    {
        _bitmap = new Bitmap(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/" + this.GifSource)).Stream);
        Source = GetBitmapSource(_bitmap);
        if (this.IsPlay && _bitmap.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif))
        {
            StartAnimate();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Close the FileStream to unlock the GIF file
    /// </summary>
    private void AnimatedGIFControl_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StopAnimate();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Start animation
    /// </summary>
    public void StartAnimate()
    {
        ImageAnimator.Animate(_bitmap, OnFrameChanged);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stop animation
    /// </summary>
    public void StopAnimate()
    {
        ImageAnimator.StopAnimate(_bitmap, OnFrameChanged);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event handler for the frame changed
    /// </summary>
    private void OnFrameChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle,
                               new FrameUpdatedEventHandler(FrameUpdatedCallback));
    }

    private void FrameUpdatedCallback()
    {
        ImageAnimator.UpdateFrames();

        if (Source != null && Source.CanFreeze)
        {
            Source.Freeze();
        }                

        // Convert the bitmap to BitmapSource that can be display in WPF Visual Tree
        Source = GetBitmapSource(_bitmap);
        InvalidateVisual();            
    }

    private BitmapSource GetBitmapSource(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;
        BitmapSource bitmapSource = null;

        try
        {
            handle = bitmap.GetHbitmap();
            bitmapSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                handle, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                DeleteObject(handle);
            }
        }
        return bitmapSource;
    }

}
```

I use it in wpf as follows:

```
<customControl:AnimatedGIFControl x:Name="faultImage" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                              IsPlay="True"
                              GifSource="Images/RouteWindow/BigFaultReportImage.gif"/>
```

I let applications run 24 hours, rising on a 1GB memory.
If it was because I forgot to clean up the memory or not?
I don't know why. Please, help me!

Comment: What about profiling your project? it will provide full info about the memory allocations. That's why profiling tool is always needed to fine-tune the performance. Sometimes it's really hard to just look in code and guess what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you create a bitmap every frame update and you never call garbage collector. Did you tried to call GC.Collect(); after InvalidateVisual();    ?